# How to find $p$-adic additive valuation of a vector?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Consider the function $$f(X)=(f_1(X),f_2(X)), ~~X=(x_1,x_2)$$ over the $p$-adic number field. So $f$ is a vector valued function from $\mathbb Q_p^2 \to \mathbb Q_p^2$.

> How to compute the $p$-adic additive valuation $v(f(X)$ ?

For example, consider $f(X)=\sum c_IX^I$, where $c_I=(a_1,a_2) \in \mathbb Q_p \times \mathbb Q_p$ is $2$-tuple and $I=(i_1,i_2)$ is the index set.

> What would be $v(f(X))$ ?

---

If $m(X)=C_IX^I$ be a monomial of $f(X)$  with $C_I=(p,p)$, then I think $v(m(X))=v((p,p))+ |I|$, where $|I|=i_1+i_2$.

Note $|I| \geq 1$. But what is $v((p,p))$ ?

I think $v(m(X)) \geq 2$ and so $v(f(X)) \geq 2$.

Any guidance please.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, could you take a concrete $f$ and tell what you want to evaluate exactly?

Comment: @reuns, suppose we have a polynomial $f(x)=px+x^6 \in \mathbb Q_p[x]$, then $v_p(f)=1+v_p(x) \geq 1$. Now I need to evaluate a function $g(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix} px_1+x_2^6 \\ px_2+x_1^7 \end{pmatrix}$. What would be $v(g)$ ?

Comment: What is $v((x_1,x_2))$?

Comment: @reuns, this is my question. How to evaluate $v((x_1,x_2))$ ? I know that additive valuation is defined on field only. Is there any generalization of additive valuation for normed space or affine space?

Comment: @reuns, in addition to my previous comment, the additive valuation is defined on ring as well

Comment: $v((x_1,x_2))=\min( v(x_1),v(x_2))$ is the natural extension (recall that $|x_1|=p^{-v(x_1)}$ is a norm, think to the sup norm on $\Bbb{Q}_p^2$)

Comment: @reuns, yes, I got it. I should have thought it in terms of $p$-adic norm instead of additive valuation. Thanks a lot. Just to check. In my above example, $v(g)=\min\{v(px_1+x_2^6),v(px_2+x_1^7)\}=\min \left\{\min \{1+v(x_1),6v(x_2)\}, \min \{1+v(x_2), 7v(x_1)\}  \right\}=\min \{1+v(x_1), 1+v(x_2)\} \geq 2.$  Is it true ?

Comment: $v(px_1,x_2^6)\ge \min(v(px_1),v(x_2^6))$ it doesn't have to be equality

Comment: @reuns, Once we know the $p$-adic valuation of a vector, I think similarly the $p$-adic valuation extends naturally to ring of matrices with entries in $\mathbb Q_p$. For example, for $a_i \in \mathbb Q_p$, I think $v\left(\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4 \end{bmatrix} \right)=\min \{v(a_1), v(a_2), v(a_3), v(a_3) \}$. Am I right ?